# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Profile>

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
  class Profile {

   final List<String> photos;
   final String name;
   final int age;
   final String education;
   final String bio;
   final int distance;

   Profile({
   this.photos,
   this.name,
   this.age,
   this.education,
   this.bio,
   this.distance
    });

    }



     class _MainControllerState extends State<MainController> {


     static  List<Profile> demoProfiles =   fetchData();

     static fetchData() async{

      final db = await Firestore.instance;
      List<Profile> list = [];
      db.collection("users").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot){
         querySnapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
            list.add(Profile(
                photos: document['photoUrl'],
                name: document['photoUrl'],
                age: document['photoUrl'],
                distance: document['photoUrl'],
                education: document['photoUrl']
            ));
            });
            });
            return list;
             }


           final MatchEngine matchEngine = MatchEngine (
           matches:demoProfiles.map((Profile profile) => Match(profile:
           profile)).toList()
            );
```

I am new to flutter.
when I run my code , I got the error :type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List .and if I change screen I will get the error:NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.  How can I solve it ?
Thank you for helping me .

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the return type of method `fetchData`

```dart
static Future<List<Profile>> fetchData() async{
```

Comment: I followed your advice and then I got some new errors . please take a look of my updated screenshot

Comment: @ZivCheung so you are trying to access an `async` function directly in `synchronous` code which will not work. So what you can do it that change the type of `demoProfiles` to `Future<List<Profile>>` then use it somewhere in an `async` function with `await demoProfiles` or you should assign the return value once the future is resolved

Comment: @ZivCheung yeah sure would love to... could you share some more details about what you are trying to implement?

Comment: I updated the original code screenshot of the original code example , I want to update the list of my data in Firestore

Comment: @ZivCheung You can you `FutureBuilder` widget to generate widget(s) showing these profiles. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873762/i-have-static-gridview-from-local-list-how-to-make-it-dynamic/61874490#61874490).

Comment: can I ask what should I put in <Map> and future:  for the future builder? thank you

Comment: if (snapshot.hasData) {
      
      
        List users = snapshot.data['data'];
        return GridView.builder(
          
           itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
             Map food = foods[index];
             return Profile(
                 photos: users[photourl'],
                 ......
             );
           }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214419/discussion-between-ziv-cheung-and-shubham-tanwar).

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you method to **getData**

```
  Future<List<Data>> getData() async {
        var response =
        await http.get(Uri.https('jsonplaceholder.typicode.com', 'users'));
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List<Data> dataList = [];
             for (var u in jsonData) {
        Data data = Data(u["name"], u["phone"], u["email"]);
        dataList.add(data);
       }
       print(dataList.length);
      return dataList;
   }
```

And display in a Card

```
         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Data Fetch"),
           ),
         body: Container(
               child: Card(
                     child: FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
                       future: getData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                   return Container(
                         child: Text("Loading"),
                          );
                 }else{
                    return ListView.builder(
                           itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                           itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                return ListTile(
                                   title: Column(
                                        children: [
                                            Text(snapshot.data![i].name),
                                            Text(snapshot.data![i].phone),
                                            Text(snapshot.data![i].email),
                                            ],
                                           ),
                                          );
                                       });
                                     }
                                   },
                                 ),
                               ),
                           ));
                         }
```

> > > Its worked for me :) :) I hope this will help you.